# Replace only the first character of a matched pattern

Tags: text-processing, sed

I need to write a sed command that reads from a file and replaces the first character in each line with 0, only in the event that the first and second character in that line is a digit (and leave the rest of the lines intact).

Comment: No, I don't kbow where to start. Any help appreciated

Comment: have a look at manual `man sed` or `info sed` and tutorials like http://www.grymoire.com/Unix/sed.html and http://code.snipcademy.com/tutorials/shell-scripting/sed/introduction

Comment: A more meaningful title (to help others, in the future) might be something like *"Replace only the first character of a matched pattern"*

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can find lines that begin with two digits using either `^[0-9][0-9]` or `^[0-9]\{2\}`

Then you can replace a single character with 0 using `s/./0/`

Putting it together,

```
sed '/^[0-9][0-9]/ s/./0/' somefile
```

or

```
sed '/^[0-9]\{2\}/ s/./0/' somefile
```